# Difference betwwen two Haproxy configurations

Tags: haproxy, high-availability

Next, I'm going to show two configurations of balancing servers. What I see, these two configuration have the same performance. So what is the utility of using backup for last server 4 on first configuration?

First config

```
listen web_cluster 0.0.0.0:1513
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    default-server port 9200 inter 2s downinter 5s rise 3 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 500 maxqueue 200
    server server-1 172.24.2.11:80 check weight 200
    server server-2 172.24.2.12:80 check weight 150
    server server-3 172.24.2.13:80 check weight 100
    server server-4 172.24.2.14:80 check backup
```

Second config

```
listen web_cluster 0.0.0.0:1513
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option httpchk
    default-server port 9200 inter 2s downinter 5s rise 3 fall 2 slowstart 60s maxconn 500 maxqueue 200
    server server-1 172.24.2.11:80 check weight 200
    server server-2 172.24.2.12:80 check weight 150
    server server-3 172.24.2.13:80 check weight 100
    server server-4 172.24.2.14:80 check weight 50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [HAProxy manual](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#5.2):

> When "backup" is present on a server line, the server is only used in load
>   balancing when all other non-backup servers are unavailable. Requests coming
>   with a persistence cookie referencing the server will always be served
>   though. By default, only the first operational backup server is used, unless
>   the "allbackups" option is set in the backend. See also the "no-backup" and
>   "allbackups" options.

In other words, the difference between the configs is that in the first one, server-4 will see *no traffic at all* unless servers 1 through 3 are down, while in the second one it will receive *some* traffic at all times.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep in mind. I think I saw a previous comment that backup server is used for  sorry pages when all nonbackup servers are down, but I don't see anymore. I don't know if it was edited.